# How to retain folder even after delete in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have a release folder under which I have branches and applied the branch policy to the folder so that it applies to all the branches created under it.

when the last branch under the release folder is delete the folder disappears also the branch policy. Next time when the branch is created under the release folder it does not have branch policy.

Answer (score 0):

> How to retain folder even after delete in azure devops

Sorry to say that this feature does not supported by Azure devops until now. The file exists **depends on** branch. As you can see that while you delete the last branch, the file will also disappeared. That means in file folder it at least has one branch, so that it has actual meanings.

You can raise a suggestion in our official [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). You can vote and comment there. while it has enough votes, the product group can consider this feature suggestion.